# what does "built into" mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I was studying Javascript lately, and I came across one statement in MDN web docs about the Javascript

> "Javascript is a highly scripting language built into browser that
> allows you to implement functionality on web pages/apps".

I do not understand the phrase "***built into***" in this context. Does it mean that Javascript is built for the browser? If yes then in that statement why doesn't it say ***built for*** instead of ***built into***?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we're being asked to analyse the semantics & syntax of a passage that's obviously not written by a native Anglophone.

Comment: We've previously answered [Question about meaning of “its built in safety feature”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21329/question-about-meaning-of-its-built-in-safety-feature) and [Built-in, In-built, Inbuilt and Builtin - I'm confused](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16886/built-in-in-built-inbuilt-and-builtin-im-confused), either or both of which might help you.

Comment: I find it extremely unlikely that sentence is exactly as it was written in any documentation. Do you have a link? It reads like an extremely poor transcription.

Comment: @Colleen [Have a look at the JavaScipt description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Introduction#relationship_between_javascript_apis_and_other_javascript_tools)

Comment: *JavaScript — A high-level scripting language built into browsers that allows you to implement functionality on web pages/apps.* is not what you wrote in your question.

Comment: Sorry!! Does that have any difference between the two? I thought it is the same statement. Please correct me that's why I came to this community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence you have found

> Javascript is a highly scripting language built into browser that allows you to implement functionality on web pages/apps.

does not read at all well in English. The phrase highly scripting is wrong and if anything should read highly scripted. The phrase built into browser would be much better as built into the browser. A detailed account of what Javascript is would be way off-topic here but in brief the browser contains an engine which runs the Javascript.

Comment: Could we say "built in the browser" instead of "built into the browser"?

Comment: No, into is much better here. Both would be understood though.

Comment: JavaScript isn’t “highly scripted” either. It’s a high-level scripting language. Highly scripted would describe some sort of interaction or communication that was planned out before it happened, or the opposite of spontaneous.

Comment: @ColleenV yes, I was focused on the grammar rather than the sense, perhaps wrongly.

Answer (score 1):

One of the meanings of *build into* is *to make something or someone an integral part of something*. In that sentence, *built into* means the JavaScript interpreter is integral part of the browser (and it has been so since 1995).

JavaScript is a high-level scripting language, not a highly scripting language, as that sentence says. (The latter phrase doesn't make any sense.)

Answer (score 0):

> Javascript is a highly scripting language **built into** browser that allows you to implement functionality on web pages/apps.

The browsers are able to understand, interpret and run the functions of the Javascript language defined in the modules.

Before Node.js came into existence, Javascript was basically a client-side programming language. Similar to HTML and CSS, Javascript features are also made available inside the browser. This is why you will find such expressions like "built-into browsers".

Note: After seeing @mdewey's answer, I just wanted to add one thing that came to mind, Javascript is a **high-level scripting language**, instead what is said like, *highly scripting* language.

P.S: I recommend you also suggest a technical person to clear out some facts.

Comment: Could we say "built in the browser" instead of "built into the browser"?

Comment: That would mean the language has been generated in the browser, which is not the case.